# Add Google analytics event tracking to javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, events, google-analytics, tracking

Is it possible to add google analytics event tracking to the folowing javascript function?

```
 $("#wScratchPad3").wScratchPad({

      scratchDown: function(e, percent) {if(percent > 80)window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';},
      scratchMove: function(e, percent) {if(percent > 80)window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';},
      scratchUp: function(e, percent) {if(percent > 80)window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';}

    });
```

I use the following analytics code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xx', 'xx');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: yes, however, we'd like to know what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hello, rex-X. I'm sorry to say that I have not tried anything. I'm a amateur coder, and this is to advanced for me.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it's possible.  You should use the latest version of Google Analytics (the analytics.js snippet).
According to Google:

> The analytics.js snippet is part of Universal Analytics, which is
>   currently in public beta. New users should use analytics.js. Existing
>   ga.js users should create a new web property for analytics.js and dual
>   tag their site. It is perfectly safe to include both ga.js and
>   analytics.js snippets on the same page.

once the analytics snippet is called on your page, you can just call the following function in your code wherever you want to track a particular event. You can give it custom category, action, and label names.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);  //label and value are optional
```

you can read all about it here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

in your example, you could do:

```
$("#wScratchPad3").wScratchPad({

    scratchDown: function(e, percent) {
        if(percent > 80) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'ScratchPad', 'scratchDown');
            window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';
        }
    },
    scratchMove: function(e, percent) {
        if(percent > 80) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'ScratchPad', 'scratchMove');
            window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';
        }
    },
    scratchUp: function(e, percent) {
        if(percent > 80) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'ScratchPad', 'scratchUp');
            window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: No problem! The best way to thank someone for answering your question on stack overflow is to accept their answer and click the up arrow  :)

Comment: You got a plus+1 up arrow from me Josh, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Google Analytics script you're using, you may be able to get away with this.  I formatted your code a bit as well to make it easier to read.

```
$("#wScratchPad3").wScratchPad({

    scratchDown: function(e, percent) {
        if(percent > 80) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'http://www.url.com']);
            window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';
        }
    },
    scratchMove: function(e, percent) {if(percent > 80)window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';},
    scratchUp: function(e, percent) {if(percent > 80)window.location.href = 'http://www.url.com';}

});
```

Can you post which analytics code you're using?  Make sure to remove the UA code.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering. I added the code to the original post.